# Load different images on page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic

I have this small script in my HTML file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1) //random number between 1 and 3

    $("body").css({ "background": "url(image" + rand + ".jpg)",
                    "background-size": "100% 100%",
                    "background-repeat": "no-repeat"
                 });
});
```

The idea is that on the server side I'm hosting 3 images image1.jpg, image2.jpg and image3.jpg. On page load, a random number between 1 and 3 is generated on the client side according to which the background image is displayed.

**Is there a more efficient way to do this?**

PS - The scenario is kind of similar to the GitHub Notifications page. Given that you've read all notifications, each time you refresh the page a different flavor of the octocat greets you :)

Comment: Maybe you can do this at server side and just send the required image instead of all three..?

Comment: You could do `body{ background-size: 100% 100%;background-repeat: no-repeat;}` in css because it remains common in all scenario..!! Just an advice..!!

Comment: You can only make that jQuery line much shorter... Otherwise it's pretty much the same, not taking in account the image called by `document.ready` despite a random background generated at server-side inside `<style>` tags or inline `<body style="">`. If you use JS only, you can only be sure that users (beasts!) with JS disabled will not see any background.

Comment: @TilwinJoy he's not sending three images, he's just requesting with JS a single `imageRAND.jpg` image

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i don't think he's sending an ajax request after page load. maybe. that info isn't provided in the question as of now.

Comment: @TilwinJoy if you use `$("body").css({ "background": "url(image1.jpg)" )};` the browser is sending to the server a HTTP *request* for an image (if not in cache).

Answer (score 1):

You can move:

```
"background-size": "100% 100%",
"background-repeat": "no-repeat"
```

To

```
body {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Since it is the same each time.

For the randomly picked image. A server side approach will need some kind of JS since you need to dynamically tell `body` what the background image is each time.

It doesn't really matter how many images you host on the server. What matters is that you have a single HTTP request to get the image.

Comment: matters if one has JS disabled... (sorry for being too picky)

Comment: Sure, in that case just hardcode the background url to a default. JS disabled means you get static HTML each time.

Answer (score 1):

Make it more dynamic.

```
<div id="imgselection">
    <img alt="test" src="https://www.example.com/slide1.jpg"/>
    <img alt="test" src="https://www.example.com/slide2.jpg"/>
    <img alt="test" src="https://www.example.com/slide3.jpg"/>
    <img alt="test" src="https://www.example.com/slide4.jpg"/>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function (jQuery) {
        var images = Array();
        var indexImages = Array();
        jQuery("#imgselection img").each(function (index) {
            images.push(jQuery(this).attr('src'));
            indexImages.push(index);
            jQuery(this).hide();
        });
        var selectedImage = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
        jQuery('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + selectedImage + ')');
      // // OR Show one image
      //  var selectedIndexImage = indexImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * indexImages.length)];
      //  jQuery('#imgselection img').eq(selectedIndexImage).show();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `window.onload` instead of `DOM ready`.

I believe the following will load the image sooner by generating `rand` and caching the image before `window.onload`:

Once `window.onload` fires, the image will be loaded from the browser cache since it has already been loaded once.

```
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
var imgCache = new Image();
imgCache.src = 'image' + rand + '.jpg';
$(window).load(function() {
    $("body").css({ "background": "url(image" + rand + ".jpg)",
                   "background-size": "100% 100%",
                   "background-repeat": "no-repeat"
                  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to make a path to the image a script that serves an image randomly.  That way it is a dedicated module of sorts and you don't need to mix it with the main  JavaScript/jQuery code.  Make sure to set the browser not to cache the images.

For example:

```
body {
    background-image: url(randomImageScript.js);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```